# There is a problem-name and/or algorithm for calculating functions which are constant on different intervals?

Tags: algorithms, efficiency

I frequently have to calculate this kind of function

[image]

Those functions have constant values on arbitrary (predefined) intervals

I wonder if there is an algorithm for fast calculation of it, so I can learn about, and implement.

My solution is to store the intervals in an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), so I can find the value of the function in O(log(n)) time, by searching the interval, but I suspect that there must be faster algorithms, maybe using wavelets, truncating polynomials, data compression, enumerating combinations/permutations.

On the case when the function is monotonically increasing, the monotonicity should be exploitable.

It should be a common problem, with lots of applications, so it has to have common solutions, but I do not know where to search.

Comment: "piecewise constant"

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: that's helpful. Thanks

Comment: Closely related: [Perfect hash functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Construction). I'd opt for two arrays: ordered interval boundaries&associated values.

Comment: An interval tree is overkill. A sorted array is enough.

Comment: Just wondering, are we evaluating over the integers, reals, etc.?  Also, how precise are the intervals, and how many of them are there?  And how much memory can we use?  None of these details are needed, but they could be significant.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your functions have very special properties known beforehand, $O(\log n)$ is optimal and achieved by dichotomic search (assuming sorted bounds).

Because in a comparison-based model, you need to find which interval contains the argument, and this takes the computation of at least $\lg n$ bits of information.

Faster can only be achieved by *computing* the interval index *from the argument value*. An obvious case is when the intervals have equal size, then the computation takes $O(1)$.

---

You could object that there could be methods working without knowing the interval index, by directly evaluating some functions for the value of the argument (in $O(1)$ ?) and combining them. But given that your piecewise constant functions have $2n$ degrees of freedom, I don't see how you could do without combining $n$ functions, implying at least $O(n)$ operations.

---

Also notice that if you need to evaluate the function at $m$ abscissas known together, you can

- sort the $m$ values in time $O(m\log m)$ or in no time if already sorted,
- merge the list of $m$ values and the $n$ interval bounds in time $O(n+m)$, which is the time to perform the $m$ function evaluations. This leads to $O\left(\dfrac nm\right)$ amortized time per evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

$O(\log n)$ is very fast.  I think it is unlikely that you will find a faster algorithm to compute such a function.

Wavelets, polynomials, data compression, and enumerating combinations/permutations do not seem relevant.

Such a function is called piecewise constant.

Comment: If a truncated/rounded polynomial (or another fast function) just gives a different value for each interval, that value can be used as a key for a dictionary retrieving the right value. It could be close to O(1). Somebody has to have thought of that.

Comment: The keys (ideally they may just be an index for an array), can grow in monotonic way. A "polynomial" may have linear terms that match only the largest interval (with highest probability of being hit), and more and more terms for the smallest intervals, so the complexity of the calculation should be spent only on the hardest intervals. That's similar to data compression. That's why I thought that data compression should have something to do here. But I do not have a clear idea.

Comment: Maybe the largest intervals can be split on different intervals to linearize the polynomial, by rising the numbers of keys. But I do not know the trade off.

Comment: @Colim, I don't believe any of that will work (hint: work out the degree of the polynomial needed, and the time to evaluate the polynomial).

Comment: Look https://i.imgur.com/Mla8yMG.png

Comment: The polynomial does not needs to have a high degree. Only to generate different values on each interval.